# Matlab: convert cell of char to cell of vector of doubles

Tags: matlab

I would like to convert a <1 x 8 cell> of chars

```
'111001'    '00'    '111000'    '01'    '1111'  '10'    '11101' '110'
```

to a <1 x 8 cell> of <1 x (length bitcode)> doubles

```
[111001]    [00]    [111000]    [01]    [1111]  [10]    [11101] [110]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: If you want to preserve the output's **length** then you have a problem saving it as `double`: there is no `[01]` `double` number in Matlab, there's only `[1]` - the leading zeros are always omitted. Would you consider re-phrasing your question? What exactly is your goal? Would you like to convert binary to decimal? would you like as an **additional** output to get the number of bits?

Comment: is your question related in any way to Huffman decoding?

Comment: It indeedly is related to Huffman coding. My algorithm to construct the Huffman tree build the codes and returns them as a <1 x 8 cell> of chars. I would like them to be as the output of the standard huffmandict function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
s = {'111001', '00', '111000', '01', '1111', '10', '11101', '110'};
d = cellfun(@(c_) c_ - '0', s, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

`'01234' - '0'` will give 1 by 5 double matrix `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` because `'01234'` is actually `char(['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'])`, and minus operation between characters will give the operation between their ASCII codes.

Answer (score 8):

here's a one liner solution:

```
 a=num2cell(str2double(s))
```

Comment: leading zeros are dropped this way, as @Shai mentioned. is there an other option? I would like to have my output as the standard huffmandict function

Comment: There is a way of course, but then you won't get a `double` as Shai mentioned, but instead a binary vector. In your question you wanted a "<1 x 8 cell> of <1 x (length bit code)> `doubles`. So if I understand you correctly, this was already answered below by @dlimpid.

Comment: Yes, I was confused. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
    s = {'111001','00','111000','01','1111','10','11101','110'}
    num = str2num(str2mat(s));
```

Comment: he wants doubles rgt? Ok, now i'm confused.

Comment: yep, I was confused too. Apparently he wants "a <1 x 8 cell> of <1 x (length bitcode)> doubles" ...

Answer (score 3):

Try using `str2num` to convert char arrays (strings) to numbers.

If you want to interpret the numbers as binary (base 2) numbers, try using `bin2dec`.

Comment: `str2num `does not operate on cell arrays.